# open directory (folder) in android

Tags: android

What is the code to open the folder, `/storge/sdcar0/0students/` to be like a screen in the picture below

```js
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/0students/");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

I have used this code, but is not required

[enter link description here](http://vb4arb.com/vb/attachment.php?aid=7342)

Comment: Your picture of the screen is missing.

Comment: Link redirect to some visual basic forum

Answer (score 0):

To open the directory **0students**, try this.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/0students/");

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");


 if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but the code does not work, and even shows an error message, greetings